# How do I delete the first line in a file?

Tags: perl, file-io, awk, line

I can't search for a particular string, since they're all very similar, but I'd like something simple to chop out the first 4 lines in a file.

They're all variable length too.  I've had a think about perl, and it all seems harder than I thought, but I'd like to do it in Perl, AWK or a shell command if possible.

Does anybody have a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Note: Instead of `destructive_process file > tempfile; mv tempfile file` you should use `destructive_process file > tempfile && mv tempfile file`. The `&&` instead of `;` prevents the original file from being overwritten if there's an error since it only does the second part if the first part succeeds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sed` is the simplest. To delete the first line of a file, do:

```
sed '1d' file.txt
```

Or, to remove the first four lines, do:

```
sed '1,4d' file.txt
```

Comment: eh, that's perfect!

Thanks to everyone who suggested sed (although -i doesn't work on this version)

Comment: Have you tested the command with big lines before posting? Although not requested it doesn't work with lines of more than 15 Mbytes.

Answer (score 13):

```
tail -n+2 filename
```

Will skip the first line in `filename` and output it to stdout.  The `-n+2` option means to start outputting lines beginning with the second line.

Of course you can substitute 2 with whatever number you need (your title and actual question content say first and fifth, respectively).

Comment: +1: This solution is much nicer than mine. I didn't know you could pass something like `+3` to `-n`.

Answer (score 5):

skip first 4 lines

```
$ awk 'NR>4' file >temp;mv temp file

$ more +5 file >temp;mv temp file

$ perl -i.bak -ne '$.>=4 && print' file
```

Comment: If the number of lines to delete is variable:  `awk -v n=$num 'NR>n' file`

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -i '1,4d' <filename>
```

will delete the first four lines of its input file. (If you only wanted the first line deleted, you could use `'1d'` instead.)

The `-i` flag stands for in-place editing, which means that the input file is also the output file, and thus the changes are written back out to the original file. If you'd prefer to have the file left intact and the modified contents simply written to stdout, just omit the `-i`.

This and many other `sed` 1-liners can be found in a handy reference here:

http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt

Answer (score 2):

```
tail -n +5 file > temp
mv temp file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -pe'1..4and$_=""'
```

as equivalent to

```
sed 1,4d
```

or

```
perl -ne'1..4or print'
```

as equivalent to

```
sed -n '1,4!p'
```

You can use `-i` same as in `sed`.

Comment: @daotoad: I noticed that flip-flop is rarely used. I noticed it even for medium experienced Perl developers. May be documentation looks complicated for first sight.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `sed -i 1d file`

A general rule :

To remove the `n` first lines: `sed '1,nd' file.txt`

 For example: `sed '1,4d' file.txt` to remove the first 4 lines

Answer (score 1):

A solution which requires no scripting language (like awk, sed, perl etc.):

```
tail -n `expr \`cat FILE | wc -l\` - 1` FILE > FILE.new; mv FILE.new FILE
```

The idea is to count the number of lines in the file, then subtract one, then pass the result to the 'tail' command.

Comment: What is the `cat` for?  Just do `wc` on the file directly.  Besides, `tail` understands `-n +5`, which starts output from line 5.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that you can pass '+N' to the -n switch of tail. Please see Mark Rushakoffs answer for a much nicer (and more efficient) solution than mine.

Comment: To be pedantic, it uses one scripting language: shell script :)

Comment: @Svante: The `cat` is needed so that the output of `wc` does not include the filename.

Comment: `wc -l < file` will suppress the file name without using `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

Use File::Tie.  That does just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Search the file for the fourth "\r\n" or "\n" and substring from that index.